# Return Year-Value that occurs more than once in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select all number of years that occur more than once in between two columns.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT YEAR(`Date1`), COUNT(*) as Counter
from (SELECT YEAR(`Date1`)
      from table1 UNION 
      SELECT YEAR(`date2`)
      from table1
     ) as year
GROUP by YEAR(`date1`)
WHERE Counter > 2;
```

I appreciate any advice!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the `UNION`.  It needs to be `UNION ALL`, or you will never find duplicates.

Then, you can simply do:

```
SELECT yyyy, COUNT(*) as Counter
FROM (SELECT YEAR(`Date1`) as yyyy
      FROM table1 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT YEAR(`date2`) as yyyy
      FROM table1
     ) y
GROUP BY yyyy
HAVING Counter >= 2;
```

Note the changes to the query:

- `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` so the subquery does not eliminate duplicates.
- Giving a column alias to the year, in this case, `yyyy`.
- Using the column alias in the outer query.
- Using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `GROUP BY` , you need to use `HAVING` not `WHERE` like following.

```
SELECT   Y , 
         COUNT(*) AS Counter 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(`Date1`) Y
                FROM   table1 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(`date2`) Y
                FROM   table1) AS YEAR 
GROUP BY Y 
HAVING    COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Note: You don't need to put `YEAR` again in your outer query, also you can put `DISTINCT`, for each column so that you don't get duplicates for the column.